# postgresql: упростить код получения строки с уникальными словами, избавиться от лишних функций

Tags: sql, массивы, postgresql, строки, оптимизация

есть такой sql запрос

```
SELECT 
    t1.id AS id,
    array_to_string(
        array(
            SELECT DISTINCT unnest(
                string_to_array(
                    STRING_AGG(t2.words, '|')
                , '|')
            )
        )
    , '|') AS words
FROM libraries t1
JOIN library_file_relationships r ON t1.id = r.library_id
JOIN files t2 ON r.file_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

- из таблицы `files` извлекаются поля `words`, которые содержат слова,
  разделённые разделителем '|'
- затем поля разбиваются на отдельные слова по разделителю '|' и
  преобразуются в массив
- из массива оставляются только уникальные значения
- которые затем опять складываются в строку через разделитель '|'

Я сделал в лоб, что данный алгоритм гарантированно работает, но как по мне происходит очень много лишних функций работы со строками и массивами, как мне кажетяся

можно ли его упростить (а значит и ускорить)?

**Нужно:** в каждой группе из полученных строк, содержащих слова через разделитель '|', создать одну строку, содержащие только уникальные слова (без повторов) через разделитель '|'

Comment: `STRING_AGG(DISTINCT t2.words, '|')`. Ну и WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY) по вкусу.

Comment: @Akina, так `t2.words` сама содержит несколько слов через разделитель '|' и предварительно надо разложить строку на отдельные части, затем накопить с другими частями из других найденных строк, удалить дубликаты и свернуть обратно в строку

на счет `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY)`  не понял

Answer (score 0):

Можно упростить  разборку-сборку так

```
select id,string_agg(w1,'|') as words
from (
   select distinct id,string_to_table(fl.words,'|') w1
   from files fl
)x
group by id;
```

Должно получиться примерно так:

```
SELECT t1.id AS id,t2.words
FROM libraries t1
JOIN library_file_relationships r ON t1.id = r.library_id
JOIN (select id,string_agg(w1,'|') as words
   from (
      select distinct id,string_to_table(fl.words,'|') w1
      from files fl
   )x
   group by id
  )t2 ON r.file_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id -- нужно ли это, вопрос
```

По комментарию, больше вариант

```
SELECT t1.id AS id,t2.words
FROM libraries t1
JOIN library_file_relationships r ON t1.id = r.library_id
JOIN (select library_id,string_agg(w1,'|') as words
   from (
      select distinct library_id,string_to_table(fl.words,'|') w1
      from files fl
      JOIN library_file_relationships r ON fl.id = r.library_id
   )x
   group by library_id
)t2 ON r.library_id = t2.library_id
```

Ваш вариант:Собрать 1-10000 строк в одну и потом разобрать на слова, выбрать уникальные и собрать в строку. И повторить это 10000 раз.

Предлагаемый: Разобрать 1000 000 строк на слова и собрать  в готовую строку для каждого library_id (libraries.id) уникальные в пределах library_id.

Представляется, string_agg  внутренний - можно пропустить и собирать DISTINCT по library_id. Умозрительно, это позволит не создавать 1 временную таблицу размером с files.
В любом случае, придется создавать временную таблицу на несколько миллионов строк(слов) и сортировать его по library_id и words.

Если запрос слишком тяжелый, делать поэтапно, по, например, 1000 library_id.

Comment: а что с производительностью такого решения?

Comment: Не зная размер files.words, сложно что-то сказать. По документации ``unnest``:``Expands an array into a set of rows`` , т.е. примерно как и string_to_table. По Вашему примеру, скорее кажется лишним ``STRING_AGG(t2.words, '|')``.

Comment: без STRING_AGG(t2.words, '|') у меня не удавалось получить результат - ошибки были

Comment: Пример данных помог бы рассмотреть задачу более детально. В первую очередь, libraries.id ->library_file_relationships->files.file_id

Comment: данные как раз можно нагенерировать - это не критично, типа `word1|word2`, `word5|word3|word1` и т.д. - сюда же мегабайтную таблицу не перетащишь

Comment: Я имею ввиду модель образец данных. например, сколько строк из files относится к одному library_id?

Comment: от 1 до несколько десятков уникальных слов в files.words, записанных в виде строки через разделитель '|', всего строк в files 1.000.000+, в libraries порядка 10.000, на одну Library_id может приходиться от 1 до нескольких тысяч files.words, но после разборки и сборки уникальных слов от 1 до нескольких сотен всего на каждый library_id